# Is it possible to copy a grid datasource to a new datasource, a new datasource that loads all data?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

Is it possible to copy a grid datasource to a new datasource, a new datasource that loads all data?
For example I have a kendo grid which has a page size of 10, how would I copy it into a new datasource which will load all the data and ignore the paging.

Comment: But should it go to the server for getting the data? If so, just copy the DataSource definition and overwrite the paging value.

Comment: i tried querying the datasource setting the paging value to 0 but the data returned to the view was only the number of the current paging.

Comment: You should set `serverPaging` to false (check documentation here: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-serverPaging)

Comment: that's what i think i am missing... gonna try sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some aspects might depend on how did you define the DataSource of the first (pageable) datasource. But basically you need to copy the original data source, then change the value for `pageSize` and `serverPaging` and finally assign it to the second grid using `setDataSource`.

Example:

```
// First DataSource definition
var ds1 = {
    transport: {
        read: ...
    },
    pageSize: 10,
    schema  : {
        model: {
            ...
        }
    }
};

// Copy ds1 definition into ds2
var ds2 = ds1;
// Change values for serverPaging and pageSize
ds2.serverPaging = false;
ds2.pageSize = 0;
// Create new DataSource object and assign it to the second Grid
grid2.setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource(ds2));
```

You can see this running in the following JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/uj6sr9ez/

Comment: thanks... this is what i've been looking for. not documented by kendo.. thaks sir onabai

Comment: @EduCielo Could you elaborate your exact question? I cannot see why it has to be a problem loading it from a server. Maybe post a separate question with your problem

Comment: Am I missing something here or does this example merely create a new reference to the same DataSource?  "var ds2 = ds1;" assigns the address of the DataSource for which ds1 is a reference.  If you change it thru ds2 you're changing the same (one and only) DataSource as ds1 points to.  You'd need to do some sort of deep clone to get a second DataSource from the first.

Answer (score 0):

From @Will comment, I think a better solution is:

```
// First DataSource definition
var ds1 = {
//  ...

// Create the new kendo datasource, so ds1 is not modified
var ds2 = new kendo.data.DataSource(ds1);
ds2.pageSize(-1);
ds2.serverPaging = false;
grid2.setDataSource(ds2);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uj6sr9ez/42/

Answer (score 0):

Please try doing this:

```
var copyDataSource= kendo.data.DataSource.create({
    data: originalDataSource.data()
});
```